# "…so beautiful that make(s) your teeth hurt": is there a heavy sarcasm or extreme envy in the expression (in a context)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Here goes a passage from a short story [read out loud online (0:24)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OdFNwvzi4H4):

*The fountains thick with black swans imported from Siberia, and if it is a fine day and a weekend, there will be wedding parties, almost entirely Asian. The grooms wear smart gray pinstripe suits and the women are in beaded gowns so beautiful they make your teeth hurt just to look at them.*

Why does the "so beautiful they make your teeth hurt" phrase in the given context course a burst of laughter from the listeners: by the heavy sarcasm towards the identical outfit of the newlyweds or by the extreme envy the author feels looking at the brides? My guess is—the former, but I may be wrong, not having found the meaning of the phrase, which to a native English speaker might mean something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So {adjective} they make your teeth hurt* has been used so much it makes your teeth hurt. I can't remember when I first heard it.  I think it is an attempt to invoke the *Exquisite*, a beauty which to behold is  a kind of pain, like drinking something ice-cold.

The comparison is very banal. It may be that juxtaposition of the exquisite and the banal that elicits the laughter. But that's just a guess.

Comment: "So {adjective} they make your teeth hurt has been used so much it makes your teeth hurt". I beg your pardon but for a non-native English speaker, it's not this trite. Besides, like I said, there's no definition for the phrase that I could find online. For the" to make one's teeth itch", yes, there is, but it would basically mean irritation which I could have gotten since it IS online.

Comment: @Rompey. No need to be begging my pardon for anything.  The fact that it's new and strange to you really has no bearing on its triteness.  It's a kind of rhetorical flourish, an exaggeration, of the "folksy" variety, like *That moonshine's so good it will curl your hair.*